# Change focus to next input using ui-keypress in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use ui-keypress directive in input fields to apply the function newline() that creates a new input field under the current(focused) one. It works ok, but I want to update this function so the focus jumps down to the newly created field.

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.min.js">                                                       
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="keypress.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="TextCtrl">

    <div  ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="task.text" ui-keypress="{13:'newline($index+1)'}" >
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

And this is script.js:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.keypress']);
myAppModule.controller('TextCtrl',function($scope){
var emptytask = '';
var tasks=[{text:'chart'}];
$scope.tasks = tasks;
$scope.newline = function(index){
    $scope.tasks.splice(index,0,{text:emptytask});
};
});
```

Comment: Where does `focus` method come from? Your `tasks` is a normal object.

Comment: I just googled js focus and found .focus(). I thought it is kinda built-in function. You can freely delete that line.

Comment: @Chandermani my question is how to modify the newline() method that it not only creates new input field by adding new empty task to the tasks array, but also chaNGES focus to that new input field. I added the last line in the function just as a placeholder:) Maby it will lead to some solution.

Comment: deleted that line for it not to mislead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try something like this in directive

```
.directive('focusOnLoad', function () {
    return {
     restrict: 'E',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          element.find('input').focus()
        },0);
     }
    }
 }
```

On HTML do

`<div ng-repeat="task in tasks track by $index" focus-on-load>`

In controller just add the new task.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it did not work. check this plukr out please http://plnkr.co/edit/UJrk0wpCNPQy6fvRiD4X. ps keypress.js is downloaded from here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/blob/master/modules/keypress/keypress.js and works ok.

Comment: @AlexBuduguru i have fixed the fiddle to show the approach http://plnkr.co/edit/sHmiZfw3qQRPDJL0DVHz?p=preview It was a idea that needed some tweaking.

Comment: better than before, but now focus always goes to the last input. I need the newly created input(not necessarily at the bottom) to be in focus. New input field appears right under the currently focused input field when pressing enter.

Comment: btw where can I read more about this issue and how you found the solution? can you give me any links to articles etc?

Comment: There is nothing magical here, which ever directive is created, it gets focus. Which ever get created last gets focus. As i understand now you are adding element to the start of the array, this way may not work. This is standard jquery

Comment: yes, If you focus the first input in the example and hit enter, the second empty input is created(as I already told, right under the input field that was previously focused). So, I need focus go to this new item.